# Convert number to string (with internal identity and no more digits than necessary)

Tags: r

I need to transfer numbers generated in R to a python program, yet they need to be text (no binary transfer allowed). No information can be lost, I mean the exact IEEE binary image that is stored in R memory must be reconstructed in python (well, apart from NANs that can have many binary images, but any reconstruction to any NAN will do).

The internal identity property is described [in this paper](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf) as (*internal form* being the binary IEEE representation; and *external form* the text output I need):

> require[ment] that conversion from internal form to external form and back be an identity function

I've already tried with `as.character(x)` and `sprintf("%.50f", x)`. In the former, information will be lost. The latter will output unnecessary characters (sequence of trailing zeroes or trailing nines that could be rounded -- without loss of information -- to 1 plus the previous digit).

Really nice if text representation is decimal, but if not possible, could also be octal, hex whatever (as long as it is still parseable somehow in python).

Comment: You want exact, yet you want to round? Seems contradictory. Do you want exact or do you want rounded? If exact, use `sprintf` with as many digits as you want.

Comment: The assumptions that we can know a priori how many digits _must_ be used for floating-point numbers is hampered by IEEE-754, where even near-integer numbers might in fact have a whole lot of `.9999999`'s (or `.0000*0001`). How are you certain that the "IEEE binary image" from R's internal storage is acceptable to python?

Comment: @Onyambu "exact" and "round" in this case are not contradictory as long as both operations (output to text and input from text) are considered; the "print" operation can "understand" that rounding at a smart location will necessarily drive the "parse" operation to rebuild the *exact* value (*exact* to the limit of storage, since we are not talking about infinite storage). The paper I've linked in the OP explains that.

Comment: @r2evans in fact I don't know; I *assume* they use standardized IEEE754 just because every machine (except maybe for Cray) does; but you have a valid point. For the trailing "99999" or "0000*1" I expect it to round (either up or down) at the correct location, to the shortest representation that will still yield the correct value upon parsing  (see my previous comment)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, since **everything** in memory is binary.   I suspect whoever asked for this doesn't know bupkis about computers.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've asked this, I know a lot more about computers - including low level details - than you wonder. My original question in fact refers to binary image of fp numbers; the OP is not about representation in memory, it's about converting to/from representation in text. It is less about machine intricacies, and more about R (and python) functions, since I don't know R enough. If you care to read the linked paper you'll know a little bit more about computers ;-)

Comment: @rslemos my apologies - I intended for "whoever asked this" to refer to the person who placed such a IMHO silly requirement on you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with base64 encoding (openssl package). The function `base64_encode` only takes characters or raw bytes so you will need to first change your data to raw, then encode. On the receiving side, you reverse the process. Here is a small example.

```
library(openssl)

set.seed(1234)
Data = rnorm(5)
Text = base64_encode(numToBits(Data))
Data2 = packBits(base64_decode(Text), type = "double")

 Data
[1] -1.2070657  0.2774292  1.0844412 -2.3456977  0.4291247
Text
[1] "AAEBAQEBAAEAAQEAAQEAAQEBAAEBAAEBAAABAQABAAAAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAABAAEAAQEAAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEAAQABAQEBAQAAAAAAAAEBAQAAAAEAAQEBAAAAAQABAAABAAEBAAABAQABAAAAAAABAQEAAAABAAEBAQEBAQEBAAABAAABAQEAAQEAAAAAAQABAAABAAAAAQEBAAEBAQEBAQABAQEBAAEBAQAAAQEAAQABAAAAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAQEAAQEAAQABAQAAAAABAQAAAAEBAQAAAAAAAQABAAABAAEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAEBAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAQEBAAABAQEAAAAAAAABAQAAAQEAAQAAAAABAQAAAQEAAQEBAAAAAQEAAQEAAQEBAAEBAAEBAAEBAQEBAQEBAAA="
Data2
[1] -1.2070657  0.2774292  1.0844412 -2.3456977  0.4291247
```

Comment: OK, but that display of `Data` and `Data2` is just what the current parser options happen to be.  The OP (who doesn't seem to understand floating-point precision) seemed to want the exact not-correct precision-limited value.  Your code probably is passing the encoded bytes correctly but the example output doesn't explicitly show that. (As opposed, perhaps, to a `sprintf('%1.40f',x` for the source and output)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an intermediate storage of data that is equally accessible between R and python, one thought is parquet files.

In R:

```r
R> arrow::write_parquet(data.frame(pi=pi), "pi.pq")
R> sprintf("%.60g", arrow::read_parquet("~/Downloads/pi.pq")$pi)
# [1] "3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875"
R> arrow::read_parquet("~/Downloads/pi.pq") == pi
#     pi
# 1 TRUE
```

In python:

```py
In [5]: import pyarrow.parquet as pq

In [26]: pq.read_table("pi.pq").to_pandas()
Out[26]: 
         pi
0  3.141593

In [27]: format(pq.read_table("pi.pq").to_pandas()['pi'][0], '.60g')
Out[27]: '3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875'
```

Close inspection will reveal that those two string representations are identical, and since in R the `== pi` is true, it is as close a storage of the full precision of a number as R can do (I believe).

One benefit of using a format like this (and arguably as industry-standard as any other implementation), the use of parquet files (and arrow in general) allows many other data types preserved in a binary-safe, fast, efficient, cross-platform container. (Though it does tend to assume *tabular* structures.)

Comment: I see that the content area of the resulting parquet file is text. However, there seem to be both a header and footer that contain binary data.  I am not sure that this meets the OP's request for "no binary transfer allowed"

Comment: Yes, I'm dancing around what the OP's underlying needs might be in case the constraint of *"Really nice if text representation"* is not strict, unnecessary, perhaps even mis-guided based on assumptions of capabilities (e.g., an X/Y problem). That's really why I chose to post an answer and start with the disclaimer about equal accessibility. It was little cost to suggest it, I think it adds value to the discussion even if it doesn't perfectly match the wording of the question. Thanks @G5W!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is similar to @G5W's, but rather than encoding the bit array, you encode the raw bytes. It makes for a shorter text string. Here's a helper function to get the bytes for a numeric array

```
get_bytes <- function(x) {
  zz <- rawConnection(raw(0), "r+")
  on.exit(close(zz))
  writeBin(Data, zz)
  rawConnectionValue(zz)
}
```

Then you can call that on the data

```
base64_encode(get_bytes(Data))
# [1] "vrbbLCRQ878+cHSUZsHRP7mhxP3eWfE/W8M4KP3DAsBzYBZmx3bbPw=="
```

Then you can decode that in python with

```
import base64
import struct
input = "vrbbLCRQ878+cHSUZsHRP7mhxP3eWfE/W8M4KP3DAsBzYBZmx3bbPw=="
bytes = base64.b64decode(input)
float_value = struct.unpack('5d', bytes)
print(float_value)
# (-1.2070657493854209, 0.27742924211066, 1.084441176683056, -2.3456977026293493, 0.42912468881105)
```